# Maven: how configure javadoc to generate all the private and package too

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am working with Maven 3.6.3, for a project based in one module, about the generation of the javadoc in the pom.xml file I have:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Where `maven.javadoc.plugin.version` is `3.2.0`.

The plugin works how is expected:

- it generates by default all the *public* and *protected* methods and classes

Now, for **developing** purposes I need include all about the `private` and `package` (methods, classes) too. What is the correct extra configuration?. It is possible in Gradle, so I am assuming it is possible in Maven too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```xml
<show>private</show>
```

to your `<configuration/>`.

Comment: What about for non-exported packages in a single-module project? I tried `<show>private</show>` but it still only shows packages that have been exported in module-info.java.

Comment: I don't have direct experience yet (I'm in the process of migrating my Taglet library) but it looks like the `--show-types` replaces `--show` and `--show-module-contents` and `--show-packages` have been added.  Likely add `--show-module-contents all` and `--show-packages all` as arguments to javadoc with `<additionalJOptions/>`.

Comment: I tried `<additionalOptions>--show-module-contents all --show-packages all --show-types private</additionalOptions>` but it is still not showing non-exported packages. I also tried with `<additionalJOptions>` which gave me a syntax error.

Do let me know if you ever get a chance to mess around with it a little bit more. I am at my wits end with trying to generate Javadocs for my module. I don't think I should have to export all my packages out just to get Javadocs.